# Apache won't start in AMPPS

Tags: apache, ampps

As title says Apache isn't starting in AMPPS. If I try to run httpd.exe from command prompt it says `the program can't start because MSVR110.dll is missing from your computer`.

**Update:** I've googled the problem and it asked me to install `microsoft visual c++ 2014 redistributable package` but still no success.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the first hit in google when searching for the error message is a page from Microsoft that explains what happens, and how to solve the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I know it's late to answer  but maybe this can help someone to figureout this issue, use a port monitor and check the http port (port 80)  if it is used by another program (like skype or another application ).

if you are under windows you can use  CurrPorts by Nirsoft

http://www.nirsoft.net/utils/cports.html

Mac OS X you can use  PortsMonitor

http://www.macupdate.com/app/mac/47212/portsmonitor

for Linux you can use Netactview
http://netactview.sourceforge.net/index.html/screenshots.html

hope that helps

Comment: How does this help to fix a missing DLL?

Comment: @teambob he is saying that installing installing msvc redistributable package didn't help like in this post forum.wampserver.com/read.php?2,123608 , I believe the message is gone but the server is still not working and this is a common problem with ampps, and this is the way I usually fix it, cheers

Answer (score 0):

change php version apache will start after that switch back to your php again